# Unit testing: toString method. Possible override?

Tags: java

My professor gave us this homework exercise and has created a project with a bunch of unit tests. Our goal is to make sure we can pass those unit tests. We have two classes. A class called Building, that has a name, a minimum floor and a max floor and a class Room, that has a building, a name and a floor. I do not understand one of the test cases and how to make sure my program passes it.

I have already created the class building and room with its getters and setters.

This is the test our professor is gives

```java
    @Test
    public void testToString() throws Exception {
        Building b = new Building("B", -1, 4);
        Room b104 = new Room(b, "104", 1);
        assertEquals("Building(B)", b + "");
        assertEquals("Room(B,104)", b104 + "");
}
```

This is what junit tells:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Building(B)
Actual   :Building@4e718207

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Room(B,104)
Actual   :Room@4e718207
```

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest to your professor that `String.valueOf(b)` is a better way of converting to a string than "concatenate with an empty string".

Comment: But basically, you need to override the `Object.toString` method. Have you tried overriding `toString` yet? What does the implementation look like?

Comment: you're getting hashcode values of objects. try using objectName.collect()

Comment: yes as @JonSkeet said you need to override toString method to get actual value instead of hashcodes

Comment: Well, we are not supposed to change the unit test itself, only write that code that makes sure that I pass the test. In any case, I think I understood, correct me if I'm wrong, by concatenating with an empty string Im basically converting my class into a string?

Comment: @OnkarMusale If that is true I think I have the answer to my question. I didn't know what. b+""; and b104+""; meant, thanks

Comment: @MárioMarques no. You're converting your **object** into a String.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. Im kinda new to POO and higher level languages.

Comment: That is the whole point of such tests: they are an executable check for the behavior of your production code. The idea is that now change the class under test to confirm the tests. By overriding toString(). That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your classes `Building` and `Room` you have to override `toString()`. In this method you have to build a string according to the test your professor gave you and then return it.

Comment: Correct, I just didn't know what ```b+"";```
 and ```b104+"";```
 meant

Comment: Maybe you should have clarified this in your question.